# Object is not coming on top/center of the Vuforia marker in Hololens, How to solve it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I want to show some object on top of the Vuforia Marker but it's coming beyond the marker. I want it on the center of the marker.

I used Unity Lerp function to force the object to come on top of the marker but still it has some deviations and it's coming anywhere on the marker.

```
  Transform child = transform.GetChild(0);
  child.parent = null;
  Vector3 _size = GetComponent<ImageTargetBehaviour>().ImageTarget.GetSize();
  Vector3 _centre = new Vector3((0 + _size.x) / 2, (0 + _size.y) / 2, (0 +   _size.z) / 2);
  Vector3 _depth = Vector3.Lerp(child.position,  Camera.main.transform.position, 0.72f);
  child.position = new Vector3(_depth.x, Mathf.Lerp(_depth.y, _centre.y, 0.03f), _depth.z);
```

Comment: Did you make the object a child of the marker? It is required, so it snaps onto it. And be aware of the rendering queue. Unity renders from top to bottom. If you have multiple objects on the same level in the hierachy, the lowest gets rendered last.

Comment: @ecco Yes,the object is child of the marker. It tracks the marker, the problem is on the mobile platforms the object appears on the center of the marker but in the hololens it's not.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a child of the marker .. it is often the simplest way but not necessary. If you make it a child of the marker simply set it to the local position you want and it should look the same way during runtime

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is executed on the marker.

First of all make the `GetComponent` call and others only once!

```
// Would be even better if you directly reference this via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private ImageTargetBehaviour itb;

// Alsonthis can probably be done once
[SerializeField] private Transform child;

// And also this should be set once
[SerializeField] private Camera _camera;


private void Awake ()
{
    if(!itb) itb = GetComponent<ImageTargetBehaviour>();

    child = transform.GetChild(0);

    _camera = Camera.main;
}
```

then later depending on your needs you can simply do

```
// Depending on your needs it coukd also be  + transform.up 
child.position = transform.position - transform.forward * XY;
```

if you want it e.g. always in front of the target independ of the camera position (meaning simply the way the target is facing). In this case however you could simply set the relative (local position) via the Inspector once and it would always keep this offset since it is a child.

Or e.g.

```
// Move XY in the vector position->camera
child.position = transform.position - (transform.position - _camera.transform.position).normalized * XY;
```

If you want it always "in front" of the target meaning closer to the camera them the target depending on the camera position.

Or simply

```
child.position = transform.position;
```

which would equal

```
child.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
```

if you simply want it in the same position as the target. But again you could simply set it up correctly via the Inspector and you should be fine.

---

The line `child.parent = null;` kind of breaks this behavior .. not sure if this was intended but once it is no child anymore it will in future stay on that position. Furthermore your line `GetChild(0)` would then fail as well since you moved the child out of the hierarchy...

Comment: Thanks for the response. Still it's coming in front or beyond the marker not on the marker. I want to track it only once that's why I'm using this line `child.parent = null;`

Comment: well then remove the offset completely. I thought you wanted it in front or on top. If not so simply use `child.position = transform.position;`

Comment: `child.position = transform.position;` with this it's coming somewhere else, couldn't even see in hololens. `child.position = transform.position - (transform.position - _camera.transform.position)` with this line it's somewhat ok but the object moves based on the distance between camera and the marker.

Comment: that's why it should be `.normalized` (=> vector with magnitude 1) and then multiplied by the desired offset such as `0.1f` for 10 cm